# Multiple Socket IP address debugging on same machine

Tags: java, sockets

I'm designing a chat service that uses Java server sockets.
When a user connects to my server with their browser I need to make sure their connection information stays the same when they open new pages on my site in their browser. So I need to keep track of their remote IP address. I am using this below, but am unable to test it as I am on a local machine.

```
client.socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()
```

I want to test my system with multiple IP address from the client conenctions but I can not do so since this method above returns the same IP as I am local. How can I go about debugging and testing such a setup in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign multiple addresses to a single NIC in Windows' Network properties->advance option.

Check out short tutorial: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-windows-8-computer

Also, you most  like have to bind the address manually,
 i.e. `client.bind("some ip");`

[image]